# Floating Dynamic Multi-Line List Items into Two Columns

Tags: css

I have a dynamic list that I need to lineup nicely into 2 columns using CSS and I'm having a terrible time with it.

The markup similar to this:

```
<ul>
<li>A is for apples</li>
<li>B is for bananas which are yellow in color</li?
<li>C is for cupcakes</li>
....
</ul>
```

When I simply give the li's a width and float them to the left they are clearing funny and end up formatted similar to this:

```
A is for apples        B is for bananas which
                       are yellow in color
C is for cupcakes      D is for dirtbag
```

I need the formatting to get the 3rd li directly under the first li - no matter the height of any one of the list items like this:

```
A is for apples        B is for bananas which
C is for cupcake       are yellow in color
D is for dirtbag
```

Each li's text is being pulled from a database and I have no control over how long each is.

*Clarification Update* - The list may also come out of the database like so:

```
<ul>
<li>A is for apples that grow on trees</li>
<li>B is for boat</li>
<li>C is for cupcakes</li>
<li>D is for dishes - that sure don't wash themselves</li>
....
</ul>
```

Requiring the formatting:

```
A is for apples that   B is for boat
grow on trees          C is for cupcake
D is for dishes -      E is.....
that sure don't wash
themselves
```

*/clarification*

**My backup plan**: The order is not particularly relevant so I have tried to split the list in half and print out the two columns in 2 separate `<ul>`'s that floats left with a defined width but with each `<li>`having a variable height and the database returning between 2-15 items, using that method the bottom of the columns don't consistently look even. I'd just rather find a better option if possible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m afraid you're out of luck until IE has css3 multi-column support.

You could of course use it and use a javascript solution for IE (there are multi-column plugins for jQuery for example), but your backup plan seems an easier solution.

Comment: I'd forgotten about multi-column, unfortunately the site gets most of it's traffic from IE so that won't work for this specific implementation.

Comment: @Terri Ann I figured as much so you're down to your backup solution or css3 with a javascript fallback, css alone is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were after?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/fe2as/

**EDIT**

JQuery approach:

```
$('li').each(function(e) {
    $var = $(this).height();
    if ($var > 25) {
        $(this).addClass('second')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('first')
    }
});
```

You will need to tweak it to allow for instances where multiple lines appear one after each other...

Comment: No, unfortunately that would only work if it was a static list but it's dynamic - a `<li>` that is two lines could appear 1st on occasion or maybe 3rd or sometimes not at all.

Comment: Well then you can measure it with JQuery - I will edit the above to show this

Comment: I'd have to integrate a toggle between first and second and use the height of the previous to override or a sum of the height of each column it and I can imagine that getting terribly convoluted on sets of 15 `<li>`'s and may still produce the same problem I encountered with my backup solution with visually awkward column bottoms. Thanks for the idea though - I may see if that will work any better than my backup plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to work in some Javascript, I used the following code to solve this same problem for IE 9+ (that's all that was scoped, so I can't guarantee it will work in older IE versions).

Basically, it floats elements left or right (via CSS with the `left` and `right` classes) depending on which column is currently shorter.

Worth noting is that this code is declared within a View object, so that first `this` references the wrapping element (in your case, the `<ul>`).

```
alignContainers: function() {
    var thisView = this,
        numOfElements = 0;

    thisView.$el.find("> div").removeClass("left right")
    .each( function() {

        if (this.offsetHeight != 0 && this.offsetWidth != 0) {
            var leftHeight = 0,
                rightHeight = 0;

            thisView.$el.find(" > .left").each(function() {
                leftHeight += this.offsetHeight;
            });

            thisView.$el.find(" > .right").each(function() {
                rightHeight += this.offsetHeight;
            });

            if (numOfElements == 0) {
                $(this).addClass("left").removeClass("right");                            
            } else if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
                $(this).addClass("left").removeClass("right");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("right").removeClass("left");       
            }

            numOfElements++;

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("left right")
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [a definition list](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/).

```
<dl>
   ...   
   <dt>B</dt>
   <dd>is for bananas which are yellow in color</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I'm unclear how that would help my wrapping problem - can you provide some information about what styles I would apply to the `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags to achieve this?